# How to develop Windows 10 style apps like Mail or Powerpoint?

Tags: windows, cordova, xaml, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to Windows 10 and I absolutely love the Modern/Metro design. I'd love to create programs for Microsoft appstore that look like the Windows Mail or Office 365 Powerpoint but I don't know if I'm on the right track:

1. I downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual Studio Code, but it seems more for web development. Should I use Cordova and web technologies to create such apps? It is using WinJS(?) but I'm wondering if XAML is a better option?
2. I've also [installed Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and put my Windows 10 in developer mode, but there is a bunch of options under C# projects: universal apps, windows forms apps, etc. Which one should I choose to do a native Windows app that looks like Microsoft Mail?

In general there is a whole bunch of options available and that is confusing. I know Java so picking up C# isn't hard for me. Also I've worked with Javascript/HTML/CSS for 4 years now and that is also comfortable for me.

I prefer performance and ease of maintenance.

Comment: If you're not trying to develop for other platforms (i.e. only for Windows  10) then c# in VS2015 is the obvious way to go. I'm not familiar with Microsoft Mail but VS comes with so many sample apps you should be able to play around  a bit and find something suitable as  a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps you mention are just regular Windows Universal apps so you can certainly do what you are asking.

1) No, VS Code is not for creating Windows Universal Apps, use Visual Studio 2015 instead (community edition is fine)

2) Your best starting point in terms of templates is Visual Studio 2015 > File > New Project >Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Windows > Universal > Blank App (Universal Windows)

It sounds like you could do with doing a few tutorials before diving into a real app. https://dev.windows.com/ is the main landing page for Windows app development. There are some great tutorials under the 'getting started' section, take the time to learn the basics now and you'll find writing your app much easier (and you'll probably produce a better app too).

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/design is also worth a look for design-specific resources.